# I am wondering how to use pub get and package download when using the internal network in Flutter

Tags: flutter

The company currently uses the internal network IP.
So I want to know the package download port and url address to use pub get.
What IPs and ports must the firewall allow to use package download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can link git repositories in your pubspec.yaml like this:

```
dependencies:
  plugin1:
    git: https://github.com/flutter/plugin1.git
```

Or you can link a private hosted package like this:

```
dependencies:
  plugin1:
    hosted:
      name: plugin1
      url: http://your-package-server.com
```

You can find more examples and a more detailed explanation [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies)